# OpenCV Python - Placing one image on top of the other

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I'm building a Sudoku Real Time solver.

I'm trying to place this image (warp):

[image]

On top of this image (original):

[image]

To make it become this image (result):

[image]

Here's what I got so far:

```
for i in range(original.shape[0]): # original and warp have the same size
    for j in range(original.shape[1]): 
        if numpy.sum(warp[i][j]) != 0: # If warp at (i,j) is not totally black
            original[i][j][0] = warp[i][j][0] # Replace original[i][j] with warp[i][j]
            original[i][j][1] = warp[i][j][1]
            original[i][j][2] = warp[i][j][2]

result = original
```

The code works but it's **very slow**. Can anybody suggests a better approach using opencv and python?

Thank you!

Comment: use `np.where`?

Comment: How do we use np.where on 3D array? I'm new to Python. Could you give me some demo code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

```
result = np.where(warp.sum(axis=-1,keepdims=True)!=0, warp, original)
```

`.sum(axis=-1,keepdims=True)` sums along the last axis, while retaining the last axis (necessary for later broadcasting), this effectively creates a mask for non black pixels. `np.where` then uses this mask to either use `warp` when mask `true` or `original` otherwise.

Comment: That works. Thank you very much! (Just need to change to warp.sum instead of original.sum). By the way do you know why my original code was that slow? It took about 10 seconds to process a 1300x800 image

Comment: because python is rather slow in general (drawback for being so convenient), numpy uses optimized c++ under the hood which is much faster.

Comment: Ohh I got it. Thanks!